# Selecting content to feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my Rails app users are able to write and publish posts.
On the homepage, I want to feature a couple of posts.

This is what I'm using to select posts at the moment:

posts_controller.rb

```
favorite_post_ids = [8,2,5]
@favorite_posts = Post.find(favorite_post_ids)
new_post_ids = [1,2,5]
@new_posts = Post.find(new_post_ids)
```

and then in the view I loop over them to display the posts.

However, once a post is deleted and the controller can no longer find it, I get an error that says

```
Couldn't find all Posts with 'id': (1, 2, 5) (found 2 results, but was looking for 3)
```

What's a better way to do this? I was thinking of individual tables, one for new_posts and one for favorite_posts and then do a relationship to posts. In the table I will have post_id referenced.

UPDATE :

I added a bunch of extra columns to posts with different types of featured content all with boolean values defaulted to false. I assign true if I want them featured.

Comment: Can you tell us, what is the criteria of favorite post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would you solve this problem?

Make your posts have flag `favorite` of type boolean. Then you'd select them like this:

```
@favorite_posts = Post.where(favorite: true).limit(3)
```

And for new posts, you can use the timestamp

```
@new_posts = Post.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3)
```

Look, no hardcoding!

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. But I'm looking specifically to select them by ID. Because if I create a favorites column to accept boolean value, I have to create columns for other kind of featured content too. For example, if I have in the posts table "featured" and "recommended" columns and only need to select a few, my worry is that majority of posts will have these columns set to false.

Comment: @Joshua: "my worry is that majority of posts will have these columns set to false" - that, by itself, is not a problem. What is your _real_ concern?

Comment: @Joshua: storing metadata in other tables ("is it featured? Is it for this new ad campaign?", etc) is a viable alternative as well. But it incurs its own costs (more complicated code, more complicated db structure, more complicated queries). Pros and cons need to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I dont encourage hardcoding. But still if that is your requirement, try

```
favorite_post_ids = [8,2,5]
@favorite_posts = Post.where(:id => favorite_post_ids)
new_post_ids = [1,2,5]
@new_posts = Post.where(:id => new_post_ids)
```